# An irreducible module $p^n$ of a finite group $G$ over a field $p$.

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

Suppose $p^n$ is a $n$-dimensional irreducible (or absolutely irreducible) module for a finite group $G$ over a field $p$. Is it true that a split extension $p^n{:}G$  will always exist? If true how do we show this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's true.

Let $M$ be the (left) module of order $p^n$. So, for each $g \in G$ and $m \in M$, a module element $gm \in M$ is defined.

Now we can define the semidirect product $E = M \rtimes_\phi G$. where the action $\phi$ of $G$ on $M$ is defined by $\phi(g)(m) = gm$, and $E$ is the required split extension with structure $p^n:G$.